# ¿Cómo hago un acumulador dentro de un método constructor?

Tags: java, poo

estoy empezando con la POO y llevo todo el día de hoy intentado meter un acumulador en un método constructor. Coloco el código de ambas clases y más abajo pongo lo que pretendo que haga el código. Esta sería la clase principal:

```
//PRINCIPAL
package e3_sumastring;

import java.util.*;

public class Uso_String {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main (String [] Args){
        CuentaLongitud mensaje1 = new CuentaLongitud(sc.nextLine());
        CuentaLongitud mensaje2 = new CuentaLongitud(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("El tamaño del mensaje 1 es: "+mensaje1.getTamaño()+"\nEl tamaño"
                + " del mensaje 2 es: "+mensaje2.getTamaño()+"\nEl tamaño total (suma del "
                        + "tamaño de los dos mensajes) es: "+mensaje1.getTamañoTotal());
    }
}
```

Y esta sería la clase en la que tengo definidos los métodos:

```
package e3_sumastring;

public class CuentaLongitud {
    private int tamañoTotal=0;
    private String cadena;

    public CuentaLongitud(String cadena) {
        this.cadena=cadena;
        tamañoTotal=tamañoTotal+cadena.length();
    }

    public int getTamañoTotal (){
        return tamañoTotal;
    }

    public int getTamaño (){
        return cadena.length();
    }
}
```

Lo que pretendo es que cuando llame al método getTamañoTotal me de la suma de la longitud de las dos cadenas, pero solo me saca la de la primera. Lo que veo que no me está funcionando es el acumulador que tengo en el método constructor, quiero saber por qué no me funciona bien esta parte del código:

```
private int tamañoTotal=0;
private String cadena;

public CuentaLongitud(String cadena) {
    this.cadena=cadena;
    tamañoTotal=tamañoTotal+cadena.length();
}
```

Lo que en mi cabeza hace este código es, recibe una cadena y en tamañoTotal almacena la longitud de dicha cadena, por lo que en tamañoTotal se almacena esa longitud x, y luego, si vuelvo a crear otro objeto e introducir el String, coger la longitud de ese string y sumarlo a tamañoTotal, pero no lo hace...

A ver si me podéis echar una mano, porque no lo veo.

¡Buenas noches y un saludo!

Comment: Vale! Muchas gracias, me queda claro. Aún no había visto para que se utilizaba el static y con esto ya se para una de las cosas que se utiliza. Muchísimas gracias a ambos, de verdad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es acumular el tamaño de la variable `tamañoTotal` cada vez que instancies un objeto. Simplemente instancia tamañoTotal como un atributo `static`. De esta forma, `tamañoTotal` será compartido por todos los miembros de la clase y realizará el sumatorio en cada instancia nueva de objeto.

> ```
> public class CuentaLongitud {
>     private static int tamañoTotal = 0;
>     private String cadena;
>
>     public CuentaLongitud(String cadena) {
>         this.cadena=cadena;
>         tamañoTotal=tamañoTotal + cadena.length();;
>         System.out.println("Tamaño total: " + tamañoTotal); // test variable
>     }
>
>     public int getTamañoTotal (){
>         return tamañoTotal;
>     }
>
>     public int getTamaño (){
>         return cadena.length();
>     }
> }
> ```

Output:

> ```
>  realizando test 
>  Tamaño total: 15 
>  de las cadenas
>  Tamaño total: 29 
>  El tamaño del mensaje 1 es: 15
>  El tamaño del mensaje 2 es: 14 
>  El tamaño total (suma del tamaño de los dos mensajes) es: 29
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Cambia a static tu varible tamañoTotal, de esta forma puede ser accedido o invocado sin la necesidad de tener que instanciar un objeto de la clase.

modificador de acceso + static + tipodato tamañoTotal = valor;